# Bootstrap Navbar Component not working in react application

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I try to use BootStrap (Navbar) Component in my react application ,But it's not show any Output and error, It just reloading page continuously.
Im using Navbar react comonent form [React Boot Strap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#brand)

What's wrong with it Please help me .

Thanks for considering my question.

**Navbar.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Nav,NavItem,NavDropdown,MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Navbar extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
                <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                  <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                      <Link to="#brand">React-Bootstrap</Link>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                  </Navbar.Header>
                  <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav>
                      <NavItem eventKey={1} to="#">
                        Link
                      </NavItem>
                      <NavItem eventKey={2} to="#">
                        Link
                      </NavItem>
                      <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem divider />
                        <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</MenuItem>
                      </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                      <NavItem eventKey={1} to="#">
                        Link Right
                      </NavItem>
                      <NavItem eventKey={2} to="#">
                        Link Right
                      </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                  </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            )
    }

}
```

`

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,  Switch,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './component/common/header.js';
import Fotter from './component/common/fotter.js';
import Navbar from './component/common/navbar.js';

import './static/css/app.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">

            <Header />
            <Navbar />
            <Fotter />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issues I can see here:

In your Navbar.js

1. **`Import {Navbar} as well from react-bootstrap`**. - Probably react got confused with your class 'Navbar' with react-bootstrap 'Navbar' which you have used inside it. That is why it does not show any error on console. The import statement should be -

   **import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from
       'react-bootstrap';**
2. You should consider changing your class name 'Navbar' to probably NavigationBar or something else you like. Just make sure you are not using same name inside the same class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yaaa... ! it's  worked , If it's necessary then  why its now showing error in terminal ..?

Comment: Because in class 'Navbar' scope react considered 'Navbar' as a known element. However, I tried it locally and it does throw error when it goes for rendering  with a message 'check Navbar.js render method...' .